# Which GUI API for PC and Android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I started writing on a new project for PC which I eventually want to port to Android. A crucial part of it will be the GUI with a lot of 2D drawing going on. In the past, I've always used Swing for my projects. Afaik, I can't use Swing on Android (and I guess it wouldn't be smart performance-wise anyways).

So is there any GUI API I can use which won't involve too much effort when porting my program to android?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: At best, you could try something based on HTML. That said, you'll get better results by coding separate frontends for the various platforms.

Comment: I'm new to Android programming myself. My solution to this same problem has been to write completely separate GUI code for the desktop and Android versions.

Comment: So there is no viable solution? Is the HTML approach practical performance-wise?